# flex mobile on android : how to stop music when application is minimized

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have developped a small application in Flex Mobile (Project actionscript mobile in flex4.7).
I have a background music.

My problem is that music is still being played when application is minimzed (Home android button): 
I would like the music to be paused when Home button is being pressed and resumed, when application is active again.

Any clues ?

Comment: I removed the Flex tags and added an ActionScript tag.  Since you're using an ActionScript mobile project [presumably in Flash Builder 4.7]; the Flex SDK has no bearing on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your document class, listen for the Stage class's ACTIVATE and DEACTIVATE events:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onAppActivated);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onAppDeactivated);
        }

        private function onAppActivated(e:Event):void 
        {
            // Play audio
        }

        private function onAppDeactivated(e:Event):void 
        {
            // Pause audio
        }
   }
}
```